# Why did the obvious type mismatch return early?

Tags: php

PHP/5.5.6

Could someone please explain to me why if I assign a variable as a string and later convert said string to an int and then compare it to the original value of a string that the situation as follows will return a true?

The arrayOfValues is an int array of numbers like so -1, 0, 0, 2, 1... etc

```
function getScore($arrayOfValues){

  $result = 'N/A';

  foreach($arrayOfValues as $item){
    if($item > 0) { $result = 0; break;}
  }

  echo $result;   // outputs 0
  if($result == 'N/A') { return -1; }   //code here passes. WHY?
  echo $result;   // outputs never makes it
  // CODE DOES based upon values calculate score

  return $result;
}
```

a call to said function within a class has the following

```
echo $foo->getScore($array);    // outputs -1
```

If I change the logic in the function to $result = -1 and the check to be $result < 0; The check now passes as expected. Why did it fail before? I know there is a type mismatch but should the computer also realize that?

Comment: More discussion apropos your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025353/strong-vs-weak-typing and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376252/what-are-the-benefits-and-drawbacks-of-a-weakly-typed-language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because

```
0 == 'N/A'
```

[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) you can read:

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically

Fix it like this:

```
if ($result === 'N/A') ...
```

Explanation (from the same place in the manual):

> The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or
>   !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value

Comment: Are you saying that in PHP a double == is like an = ? Also I didn't want a fix, I wanted an explaination.

Comment: no. In the meanwhile I've added some words from the manual and a link

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I find this interesting cause the logic I had there was working and now it all of sudden isn't. Could of been I removed a single = and never noted it. Must go back to svn and double check that.

Comment: One more question how is 0 == 'N/A' if I were to convert the string N/A to an int it would be 0? Or am I declaring the 0 is equivalent to N/A ? I noted the first example in the document where var_dump(0 == "a"); // 0 == 0 -> true.

Comment: yes, if you convert `"N/A"` to an number you get `0`. If you convert `"3.14ABC"` to a number you get `3.14`, and so on. Conversion to a number happens when either operand of the comparison is a number, or both operands are numeric strings (which means that `"2.0" == "2"`)